# get highest value with each character from series

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have text file in which values are like

VER A 150
VER A 56
VER A 131

VER Z 208
VER Z 209
VER Z 250

VER W 300
VER W 200
VER W 124

it can be more character with the series. Now i want to get highest value from each charater like W300,Z250,A150
I am using .net webform application with C#

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you show us some code maybe?

Comment: you can do this by creating if statements from a to z but i don't want to do that

Comment: Seems like something to use regex on, parse the numeric part of each one, and then compare the values, grouped by that A-Z letter.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a separator between each term in the series? Like a comma or some other character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Regex.  I used StringReader but you can change to StreamReader to read from file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication103
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                        "VER A 150 VER A 56 VER A 131\n" +
                        "VER Z 208 VER Z 209 VER Z 250\n" +
                        "VER W 300 VER W 200 VER W 124\n"
                    ;

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string line = "";
            string pattern = @"[^\d]+\d+";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                string[][] splitData = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x => x.Value.Trim()
                    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToArray())
                    .ToArray();
                var result = splitData
                    .Select(x => new { letter = x.Skip(1).First(), number = int.Parse(x.Last()) })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.number)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("letter = '{0}', number =  '{1}'", result.letter, result.number);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


}
```